# Django Sum Annotation with Foreign key

Tags: python, django

I am working on a project and noticed that the Django `Sum()` annotation is not working properly when you use it to make a sum of a field with a foreign key.

For example when you have visits to a website on which someone can place an order. The `Order` model has a link to the `Visit`model because you can place multiple orders in one visit. However, orders that are not coming from the website don't have a website visit. For these orders, the visit will be `NULL`. When I do the following, the calculation is not correct (the value is far too high).

```
visits = visits.annotate(order_total = Sum('order__total'))
```

When I change `Sum`to `Avg`, the calculation is done correctly. Is there a logical explanation for this?

Comment: show your data example, please

Comment: I just found out that the far too high values are a multiple of the original number. I think this has something to do with distinct values? For example: 3978.30 becomes 51717.90 (x13) and 189.90 becomes 3418.20 (x18).

Comment: @user2621686 What does you original `visits` query look like?

Answer (score 1):

Solved it using

```
from pg_utils import DistinctSum

visits = visits.annotate(order_total = DistinctSum('order__total'))
```

Turns out the `Sum` couldn't handle distinct values.